# KNIME: Error while creating node dialog for 'File Reader'

Tags: knime

when I try to use a File Reader  I have (often) this error Error while creating node dialog for 'File Reader': URI is not hierarchical.

Do you have any idea of what is causing this problem?

Thank you very much

Here is my log:

```
2018-01-09 18:50:31,599 : DEBUG : main : Node : File Reader : 0:206:208 : Error while creating node dialog for 'File Reader': URI is not hierarchical
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsUriSupport.fromUri(WindowsUriSupport.java:122)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.getPath(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:92)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:138)
    at org.knime.core.util.FileUtil.resolveToPath(FileUtil.java:1127)
    at org.knime.core.node.util.FilesHistoryPanel$FileReaderCheckLabel.checkLocation(FilesHistoryPanel.java:328)
    at org.knime.core.node.util.FilesHistoryPanel.fileLocationChanged(FilesHistoryPanel.java:952)
    at org.knime.core.node.util.FilesHistoryPanel.access$2(FilesHistoryPanel.java:946)
    at org.knime.core.node.util.FilesHistoryPanel$4.insertUpdate(FilesHistoryPanel.java:513)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:669)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1669)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxEditor$BorderlessTextField.setText(BasicComboBoxEditor.java:144)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxEditor.setItem(BasicComboBoxEditor.java:87)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI$WindowsComboBoxEditor.setItem(WindowsComboBoxUI.java:507)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.configureEditor(JComboBox.java:1404)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI$Handler.contentsChanged(BasicComboBoxUI.java:1864)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:93)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:131)
    at org.knime.core.node.util.FilesHistoryPanel.updateHistory(FilesHistoryPanel.java:844)
    at org.knime.core.node.util.FilesHistoryPanel.<init>(FilesHistoryPanel.java:631)
    at org.knime.base.node.io.filereader.FileReaderNodeDialog.createFileNamePanel(FileReaderNodeDialog.java:283)
    at org.knime.base.node.io.filereader.FileReaderNodeDialog.<init>(FileReaderNodeDialog.java:261)
    at org.knime.base.node.io.filereader.FileReaderNodeFactory.createNodeDialogPane(FileReaderNodeFactory.java:126)
    at org.knime.core.node.Node$1.run(Node.java:2069)
    at org.knime.core.node.util.ViewUtils$3.run(ViewUtils.java:353)
    at org.knime.core.node.util.ViewUtils$2.run(ViewUtils.java:155)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

2018-01-09 18:50:36,581 : DEBUG : main : NodeContainerEditPart :  :  : File Reader 0:206:208 (IDLE)

Answer (score 1):

please find your answere here in our forum: https://www.knime.com/forum/knime-users/error-while-creating-node-dialog-for-file-reader-uri-is-not-hierarchical#comment-28960

To resolve this, please go to the following folder: \knime-workspace.metadata\knime

and delete the files named  history_ASCIIfile

Comment: Great to see one of the KNIME team here to help out! I think SO policy is that rather than just posting a link, you should include the relevant information from the linked page in your answer - could you edit that in?